# Javascript Map of United States with Geocoordinate Plots

Tags: javascript, maps, geocoding

I'm looking for an open source or inexpensive option for a simple map of the united states to plot geo points on OR fill in states with colors like Google Analytics does for traffic.

I don't want anything fancy, just a map with states and the ability to darken areas, states or plot dots on it for a location service I'm building.

Google Maps can plot the markers, but I want this to be stupid simple and a little less feature rich.  Other popular mapping softwares out there are also too feature rich (Open Maps, MapQuest, etc.).

[image]

Comment: this link has a bunch of links to geocoding software http://code.google.com/p/gpicsync/wiki/OtherGeocodingSoftware all free

Comment: So I want something that is a pure javascript solution, even with a "light" feature would be best.  Let me see if I can get a good image together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

http://www.ravelrumba.com/code/demos/us-map-raphael/demo-animated.html

This is a Javascript map of the US, with roll-over states. It uses the Raphael library. The Github code also includes links to the SVG map that he used as the source data, and a link to a tool for converting SVG to JS data suitable for Raphael to use.

The [Raphael library](http://raphaeljs.com/) itself has a similar demo on their own site for Australia.

I hope that helps.

Comment: That's really awesome.  Do you happen to know of any geocord overlay's here?  Regardless this does handle most of the requirement!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help much further. But the good news with the SVG->Raphael converter is that its existence means that there's a heck of a lot of SVG data out there that you can use. And on top of that, other vector formats can be converted easily to SVG using tools like Inkscape. It makes the search a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

Another option, is this jQuery plugin called [Geo](https://github.com/AppGeo/geo). Not really sure how lightweight you want it to be.

You can also have a look at their docs, http://docs.jquerygeo.com/, for examples of the complexity.